# Geometry nodes, How to offset points on face along normal direction by random value?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, normals, instances, random

Im trying to scatter Swords along of a giant monster and i had a rather good first time working with geometry nodes.

**My question is: How do i offset the different points on my mesh that where generated by the "Distribute Points on Faces" Node along their normals by a random value each?**

In this example i would like to have the swords be placed in different depths inside of the titan.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, this solved the problem. For anyone from the Future: I deleted the index node for a random displacement, as the index node somehow made the location offset unified.

Comment: You are welcome